# Creating a register link inside of ko text

Tags: knockoutjs, register, hreflang, login-register

Fairly easy question for most but it's somewhat tricky and I'm having issues.

```
            <span class="note" data-bind="fadeVisible: isPasswordVisible() == false"><!-- ko i18n: 'You can create an account now or after checkout. Click the ‘Next’ button below to continue as a guest.'-->$
```

I want to hyperlink "create" to the register page if they click on it.

I've tried adding `<?= $block->escapeHtml(__("<a href='%1'>login</a>", $block->getUrl('customer/account/login'))) ?>"'>`

```
<a class="action action-register primary" data-bind="attr: {href: registerUrl}">
                        <span data-bind="i18n: 'Create'">
```

and a few other things but no success.

**Magento_Checkout/web/template/form/element/email.html**

```
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<!-- ko ifnot: isCustomerLoggedIn() -->

<!-- ko foreach: getRegion('before-login-form') -->
<!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
<!-- /ko -->
<form class="form form-login" data-role="email-with-possible-login"
      data-bind="submit:login"
      method="post">
    <fieldset id="customer-email-fieldset" class="fieldset" data-bind="blockLoader: isLoading">
        <div class="field required">
            <label class="label" for="customer-email"><span data-bind="i18n: 'Email Address'"></span></label>
            <div class="control _with-tooltip">
                <input class="input-text"
                       type="email"
                       data-bind="
                            textInput: email,
                            hasFocus: emailFocused,
                            mageInit: {'mage/trim-input':{}}"
                       name="username"
                       data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-email':true}"
                       id="customer-email" />
                <!-- ko template: 'ui/form/element/helper/tooltip' --><!-- /ko -->
                <span class="note" data-bind="fadeVisible: isPasswordVisible() == false"><!-- ko i18n: 'You can create an account now or after checkout. Click the ‘Next’ button below to continue as a guest.'--><!-- /ko --></span>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!--Hidden fields -->
        <fieldset class="fieldset hidden-fields" data-bind="fadeVisible: isPasswordVisible">
            <div class="field">
                <label class="label" for="customer-password"><span data-bind="i18n: 'Password'"></span></label>
                <div class="control">
                    <input class="input-text"
                           data-bind="
                                attr: {
                                    placeholder: $t('Optional'),
                                }"
                           type="password"
                           name="password"

                           id="customer-password"
                           data-validate="{required:true}" autocomplete="off"/>
                    <span class="note" data-bind="i18n: 'You already have an account with us. Sign in or Click the ‘Next’ button below to continue as a guest.'"></span>
                </div>

            </div>
            <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('additional-login-form-fields') -->
            <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
            <!-- /ko -->
            <div class="actions-toolbar">
                <input name="context" type="hidden" value="checkout" />
                <div class="primary">
                    <button type="submit" class="action login primary" data-action="checkout-method-login"><span data-bind="i18n: 'Sign In'"></span></button>
                </div>
                <div class="secondary">
                    <a class="action remind" data-bind="attr: { href: forgotPasswordUrl }">
                        <span data-bind="i18n: 'Forgot Your Password?'"></span>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
        <!--Hidden fields -->
    </fieldset>
</form>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Here's my code:

```
 <span class="note" data-bind="fadeVisible: isPasswordVisible() == false"><!-- ko i18n: 'You can'--><!-- /ko -->
                <a class="note" data-bind="attr: {href: window.checkoutConfig.registerUrl}"> <span data-bind="i18n: 'Create'"></span></a>
                <span class="note" data-bind="fadeVisible: isPasswordVisible() == false"><!-- ko i18n: 'an account now or after checkout. Click the ‘Next’ button below to continue as a guest.'--><!-- /ko -->
```

**It looks like this below.. not all on one line but create is linking.**

You can Create

an account now or after checkout. Click the ‘Next’ button below to continue as a guest.

Comment: Is this in a HTML or PHTML file?

Comment: it's an html file... i'll post the contents of the full file. @BenCrook

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presuming you are loading this template on the checkout you can use `window.checkoutConfig.registerUrl`.

Combine this value with `data-bind` like so and it should just work:

```
<a class="action action-register primary" data-bind="attr: {href: window.checkoutConfig.registerUrl}">
    <span data-bind="i18n: 'Create'"></span>
</a>
```

You was using `registerUrl` which unless you have defined in the scope of the KO component will be undefined.

Using your other example:

```
 <a class="note" data-bind="attr: {href: window.checkoutConfig.registerUrl}, fadeVisible: isPasswordVisible() == false"><!-- ko i18n: 'You can create an account now or after checkout. Click the ‘Next’ button below to continue as a guest.'-->$
```

Comment: How do i add that bit of code into this ?                 <span class="note" data-bind="fadeVisible: isPasswordVisible() == false"><!-- ko i18n: 'You can create an account now or after checkout. Click the ‘Next’ button below to continue as a guest.'-->$

Comment: That created a button so it essentially worked but i just want to href the word "create" in that ko string. @Ben Crook

Comment: To only add the `href` to the word then you want to change the flip the `a` and the `span` around then only the word will be the link and not the whole button.

Comment: I've updated my answer with the other example

Comment: I posted on the very bottom of my original post.... look how it's showing up on two lines. Not sure what i've done wrong here.

Comment: I marked it as the answer because you've already been a huge help. Just one last question see above comment and then the reedit in my original post... that would be super if you could help me fix that too.

Comment: @Singleton that sounds like a CSS issue, it's hard to know what the cause is without debugging the site. Maybe `display: block` and/or `width: 100%` will help or possibly `white-space: nowrap;`